# Partially transparent shader occluding objects in THREE.js

Tags: three.js, glsl

I am making a game with a fog of war layer covering the board. I want to have a cursor that shows up when the player mouses over a tile, and I'm implementing this with a glow effect around the tile, also implemented using a shader.

I'm running into a strange issue: the glow effect works fine for positive x values (when the camera is set at `x = -250`, `y = 250`) but I can't see it for negative x values unless the camera gets rotated to almost completely vertical (or I move the camera *underneath* the fog of war layer).

It's hard to explain, so I've made a CodePen demonstrating the problem: https://codepen.io/jakedluhy/pen/QqzajN?editors=0010

I'm pretty new to custom shaders, so any insight or help would be appreciated. Here's the shaders for the fog of war:

```
// Vertex
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
  vec3 cRel = cameraPosition - position;

  float dx = (20.0 * cRel.x) / cRel.y;
  float dz = (20.0 * cRel.z) / cRel.y;

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                modelViewMatrix *
                vec4(
                  position.x + dx,
                  position.y,
                  position.z + dz,
                  1.0
                );

  vColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.7);
}

// Fragment
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

And the shaders for the "glow":

```
// Vertex
varying vec4 vColor;
attribute float alpha;

void main() {
  vColor = vec4(color, alpha);

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix *
                modelViewMatrix *
                vec4(position, 1.0);
}

// Fragment
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vColor;
}
```

The math in the vertex shader for the fog of war is to keep the fog in a relative position to the game board.

Tagging THREE.js and glsl because I'm not sure whether this is a THREE.js exclusive problem or not...

Edit: version 0.87.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example looks pretty weird. By setting `depthWrite:false` on your fog material the two boxes render.

**version 0.87.1**

Comment: Do you mind me asking what you mean by "weird"? But this definitely works and looks to be the intended use! From the docs: "When drawing 2D overlays it can be useful to disable the depth writing in order to layer several things together without creating z-index artifacts."

Comment: I cant tell where the fog of war is positioned without digging too much into the code. I think you're doing something wrong with that, and if you rely on three to sort things they may be off for what you intend to do. If you are working with terrain always seen from birds perspective it would make sense to have layers - possibly as different `THREE.Scene`s which you would "manually" render in the desired order.

Comment: Ahhh I get it. Thanks for the advice!